Cannot change the syntax color of punctuation in a theme
in the scope inspector you can see I'm setting the color of the brackets to #666 but they always show up as a blue color.  Is there like a cheat sheet somewhere where we can figure this stuff out?  Not sure why they had to make this so difficult.  It's basically me just fumbling around guessing which part goes where for the past 3 days.


I figured it out.  You gotta add this.
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,

Without it your colors won't show.  FFS
